# Permissions in a MAMP development environment

Tags: permissions, file-upload, mamp

I use MAMP as my local development environment. A persistent problem I have is reliably setting folder/file permissions.

For example, I currently have an images folder I need 666 permissions on. In the more info menu in the mac finder my permissions are read & write. However in the Dreamweaver permissions dialog the same folder has 000 permissions. This resets to 000 every time I leave the dialog.

So I have one screen saying I have full permission and another saying I have none for the same folder. When attempting test uploads to this folder, my script returns an error when moving the file from the tmp location.

chmod ($directory, 0755) returns false.

The temporary file exists

Comment: I am willing to try the terminal interface to set permissions - although my Applications folder doesn't exist apparently with Ls -l - instrutions on that would be appricated

Answer (score 0):

A folder should have an execute bit, in this case 777.
Without it, the folder can't be read.

Comment: ok, but how do I set that reliably when my permissions are reset every time?

Comment: What filesystem is that folder on?
FAT and NTFS can't work with Unix permissions.